# How to remove multiple symbols from column in Biq Query?

Tags: google-bigquery

How to replace the symbols from below string?

```
"- , KALIRHAT, - , Bagribari, Jalpaiguri, West Bengal Kalirhat Kalirhat   Bagribari DHUPGURI WEST BENGAL 735210"
```

Desired Output:

```
"KALIRHAT Bagribari Jalpaiguri West Bengal Kalirhat Kalirhat   Bagribari DHUPGURI WEST BENGAL 735210"
```

I have tried replace and regexp_replace but not got the desired output.

Comment: Are there any different variations to the string? if you only want to keep characters and numbers and remove everything other, try this                          
regexp_replace("- , KALIRHAT, - , Bagribari, Jalpaiguri, West Bengal Kalirhat Kalirhat Bagribari DHUPGURI WEST BENGAL 735210",
r"[^a-zA-Z0-9]+", " ")

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick:

```sql
with t as (
  select "- , KALIRHAT, - , Bagribari, Jalpaiguri, West Bengal Kalirhat Kalirhat Bagribari DHUPGURI WEST BENGAL 735210" as str
) 

select
  array_to_string(
    regexp_extract_all(str, r'[A-Za-z0-9]+')
  , ' ') as cleaned
from t
```

You can further refine the regex if needed